# Hiding tag in a subequations and align environment also centring

Tags: align, subequations, tags

I need to hide tags inside `subequations` and `align` environments. I do not want to use `\tag{}`, the tag should be placed automatically when I typeset. Here it is,

```
\begin{subequations}
\begin{align}
H(x,t) = H_0 (x) + t H_1 (x) + t^2 H_2 (x) + ... ,  \qquad \qquad  \qquad \qquad \\ \notag
\mbox{with the dominant term being}  \qquad \qquad \qquad \qquad \qquad \qquad \qquad \qquad  \qquad \qquad \qquad \\  
H_0 = - F(x) + m_0 + (x - y)\theta _0 ,    \qquad \qquad   \qquad \qquad \\  \notag
\mbox{and remaining orders}  \qquad \qquad \qquad \qquad \qquad \qquad \qquad  \qquad \qquad \qquad   \qquad \qquad \qquad \\  
H_1 = m_1 + (x - y) \theta_1 ,   \qquad \qquad   \qquad \qquad  \qquad \qquad \\
H_2 = m_2 + (x - y) \theta_2 .  \qquad \qquad \qquad \qquad  \qquad \qquad
\end{align}
\end{subequations}
```

It works but it is ugly. Also the equation tags are placed in the line after the equation which should be the same line. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Why are you using an `align` environment but not providing any alignment points?

Comment: @Mico, would you like to expand that what you just meant ? e.g. alignment points.

Comment: Alignments points are provided by `&`. They're used in Zarko's answer to align the four `=` symbols.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suppose, that you like to have something like this:

[image]

In your code sniped are all `quads` surplus. For text between equation in `align` environment is intended `\intertext{...}`. Use of `align` has sense if you with `&` determine anchors to which equations are aligned:

```
\begin{subequations}
\begin{align}
H(x,t) & = H_0 (x) + t H_1 (x) + t^2 H_2 (x) + ... ,  
\intertext{with the dominant term being}                         
H_0    & = - F(x) + m_0 + (x - y)\theta _0 ,             \\ 
\intertext{and remaining orders}                                
H_1    & = m_1 + (x - y) \theta_1 ,                      \\
H_2    & = m_2 + (x - y) \theta_2 .  
\end{align}
\end{subequations}
```